# To update the global variable and to use the updated value in second runtime of program

Tags: c++

in a prog I initialise `a = 3` (assume global variable) and then change the value of `a` in a function and hence the value of a is updated when I run the program.

Now, when I run the program for second time the value of a is not updated,it is same as `a = 3`.

How should I update the value of `a` so I can use the updated value when I run the program next time?

Comment: Can you provide I minimal working example? It is hard to tell what you mean from your question (but it looks like you need to save the value of `a` to disk).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @norok2 
The problem is this:
For admin user in a program I (suppose) initialise int password=1(without password prog cannot be continued).Now,the admin changes his password in first runtime prog(suppose password=2)and when I run the program for second time the value of password is still 1, it is not updated and password remaining same.

Comment: @user160046 code?

Comment: @norok2 you are right,I need to save the value of a to disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static storage of the program (where global variables are stored) is there for the life of the program, not of the computer.

Each process (program) running on a computer gets a defined area of RAM memory from the OS for it's use.

This memory holds everything needed for the process to run - including the code running, readonly (and const) variables, the stack (where local variables resides), the heap (where dynamically allocated variable resides) and the static variables and some more stuff.

When the program exits, this memory is freed and is no longer associated to this process, or to any process, until reassigned.

Save the data to a file (on the hard drive) if you want to use it in two distinct runs.

Comment: @user160046 Edited, FYI.

Comment: But is there any other way as I want to use one variable value for more than one runtime of program and storing one variable in a file doesn't seem to be much a solution.

Comment: Use a file. If I understand correctly, this is some kind of access moderation? It's classic to use files for that. Choose the format you want and implement a nice interface for accessing the file. Also, you might want to store other values in the future.